# .append() not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

This scripts works in all browser's but IE7..

Overview: I got a page of products (li.prod). Each product has an image (li.prod div.mainpic img). That image has a title attribute  which I am using to add a class of the same name to the appended . Then all the brands are shown automatically by using css.

```
$('li.prod .mainpic').each (function() {
  var jThis = $(this);
  var mainImages = jThis.find('img');

  jThis.prepend('<div class="prod-logo"></div>');

  var targList = jThis.find('div.prod-logo');

  mainImages.each(function() {
    newClass = $(this).attr('title');
    targList.addClass (newClass);
  });
});
```

Anyone know of a solution that will work for all browers?

Comment: I don't see append at all in your code. Besides that, it looks fine, although I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Something is wrong here, you are looping through mainImages and setting the class in targList.

Comment: Maybe because you're prepending and not appending?

Comment: are you trying to add multiple classes (from each image title) to the `.prod-logo`?

Comment: This code needs to be in $(document).ready if it is not.  You cannot manipulate the dom in IE before the ready event has fired.

Comment: I updated the question and added the overview of the what I am trying to do, which works but not in IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the code. I just needed to declare the variables.

```
var $jThis = null; 
var $mainImages = null; 
var $newClass = null;
var $targList = null; 

$('li.prod .mainpic').each(function () {
var jThis = $(this);
var mainImages = jThis.find('img');

jThis.append('<div class="prod-logo"></div>');

var targList = jThis.find('div.prod-logo');

mainImages.each(function() {
    newClass = $(this).attr('title');
    targList.addClass(newClass);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this fiddle in IE Tester's IE 7 emulator and had no issues. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

Version with prepend:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/aBcVX/

Version with append:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/aBcVX/2/

Version with appendTo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/aBcVX/3/

Version with after:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/aBcVX/4/

Comment: I got a PC setup with ie7 on it and the div is not appending or prepending.

Comment: @Buildingbrick I added an appendTo and an after example as fiddles. Give them a try.

Comment: I would check your set up on the computer you are using to test. I found a Windows XP (SP3) desktop running IE7 (7.0.5730.11) and all the fiddles ran fine.

Comment: yea, I am on an old computer for sure. Problem is the people that approve this is on the same type of machine. Thanks for the help! FYI - I got a bunch of jquery code that doesn't work in IE7 so must be some kind of DOM/Synthax/ thingy. But anyways it got approved so we are good to go. Thanks again.